# Moving a folder and all contents to another folder

Tags: file, batch-file, move, directory

I am looking for a way to move a folder and all files and folders in it's directory to another folder. The file path for the the two folders I am using is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder1`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder2`

The break in the path causes command prompt to think that there are two file paths instead of just one. It returns ***"invalid syntax"*** and after hours of trying to find a solution, I can't get anything to work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Charlie.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose each path in quotes.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder1"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder2"
```